# Счётчик выполнения программы python

Tags: python, время, таймер, счетчики

Хочу добавить отображение полного времени работы программы (начиная с момента запуска кода). Какие посоветуете библиотеки, кроме time?

Comment: Уточните - какого типа у вас код и какой вы хотите таймер - чтобы только по окончании работы, или всё время работы чтобы выводился? Для кода с циклами очень удобно использовать библиотеку `tqdm`, например.

Comment: все время работы выводился

Comment: И всё же какая у вас структура кода? Если есть какой-то основной цикл, то подключаете `tqdm`, меняете буквально одну строку в коде и всё, будет вам прогресс-бар.

Answer (score 4):

Можно считать время выполнения так:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time # используется в качестве примера

start_time = datetime.now() # включаем счетчик

#Тут выполняются действия
time.sleep(5) # останавливаемся на данной команде на 5 сек

print(datetime.now() - start_time) # вычисляем время выполнения
```

Время выполнения:

```
0:00:05.004949
```

Если нужно отслеживать время во время работы кода:

```
import time
from tqdm import tqdm

mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in tqdm(mylist):
    time.sleep(1)
```

Выводом будет индикатор выполнения.